# Dowell 1-D Eddy Current Model

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux

About this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9628850/), I have a question; please see the yellow part.

[image]

I don't understand why the current density distribution in
the conductor is only related to the y-coordinate.

Can someone tell me in a simple way how to understand that?

Answer (score 0):

1-D is one dimensional.  The width (D) is much larger than the thickness (h) so the approximation assumes that the end effects are negligible.  Instead of a rectangular conductor, if we ignore the edge effects, we look at it is if it were a section of a conductor with current in only the "z" direction with "D" infinitely wide. If D was infinite, there would only be a difference in the current density distribution in the "y" direction (the current density in the "x" and "z" directions would be constant for any "y" value.)   So the calculation of current density would only be dependent on the value of "y" anywhere in the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

As you can intuitively understand, it isn't only related to the y-coordinate, but to both x and y.

The problem is that calculating the H field in two dimensions for a rectangle is not something trivial, and assuming only one dimension is quite confortable for calculations and, except for a few margin cases, it does not introduce a large error in the result.

The author assumes that, as the cross section of the rectangle is really thin, it is safe to assume that the part of the current density distribution that is actually 2D (in the short faces of the rectangle) is negligible compared to the part where it is 1D, which is along the long faces of the rectangle.

There are a few nice papers about this, for example: [Fringing Field Formulas and Winding Loss Due to an Air Gap](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4277910/)